# Contextual Filters via Taxonomy

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I am in the process of creating a View for my Drupal site and I am attempting to add a contextual filter by Taxonomy so I've added the `Content: Has Taxonomy term ID (with depth)` filter and selected the `Specify validation criteria` option and selected the Taxonomy that I wanted to work with. I also used the filter value type of `Term name converted to term ID` yet when I attempt to preview the filtered elements, I get the no results behavior. What should I be typing to call the filtered elements correctly?

Atm, to provide a concrete example, I have tried `my_view/mississippi-river` to call all nodes tagged with the Mississippi River taxonomy term via hierarchical select. Again, this leads me to the no results behavior. Additionally, how would I call a child of the Mississippi River Taxonomy term? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Contextual filters are just the term. So in the contextual filter input box for the Views Admin you would put `mississippi-river` as an example. In addition to `Term name converted to Term ID` you want to be sure you check the box for `convert spaces to dashes` further down in the `specify validation criteria` or else "mississippi-river" will not be found because it's expecting a space and you're providing a dash.

For the parent/child filters you're trying to achieve look at [Taxonomy Edge](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_edge). The -dev release contains some contextual filters for "parents" and "children" of stuff.

Comment: also make sure that you have selected **Save term lineage**

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have double-checked everything yet I am still unable to get the desired result. Could it be due to the fact that I'm using the `Hierarchical select` module as a content-type? "also make sure that you have selected Save term lineage" -- where is this interface where I can select `Save term lineage`?

Comment: @user32172 Edit the field, go to `Widget Type` tab, there you will see it under `Hierarchical Select configuration`